# smooth transitions in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

A simple ball movement transition in d3.js using SVG.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eNe3U/1/

When I run above example, the ball looks blurred during the transition and the tranistion is not smooth.

Is there any option to get smooth transition in d3.js or am I missing something here?

Code :

```
var width = 720, height = 580;
var padding = 50;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width",width)
.attr("height",height);     

var circle = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx","100")
      .attr("cy","100")
      .attr("r",10)
      .attr("stroke","red")
      .attr("stroke-width","1")
      .attr("fill","steelblue");


circle.transition()
     .duration(2000)          
     .attr("cx","600")
     .attr("cy","700")            
     .attr("fill","green");  ​
```

Comment: perhaps a higher framerate could do the trick

Comment: Which browser is this on - this looks good to me on Chrome, although there are some clipping artefacts. But otherwise smooth and not "blurred".

Comment: If I'm seeing the same thing, my suspicion is that it's just a feature of a small high contrast shape moving across a pixelated LCD. Doesn't seem like anything to do with D3 or SVG to me, and I'm not aware of any related settings.

Comment: I agree with Richard Marr, on my laptop I see som blury effects, otherwise, with the much better screen of the desktop it's very smooth, maybe it has something to do with the refreshing delay of the screen.